# icefaces 3 combine ice and ace component on the same page , problems with the style

Tags: styles, ace-editor, icefaces-3, ice

I am using ace:daaTable and other ice component on the same xhtml page . 
when I click oמ ice:commandButton the page style is changing.

I tried to define "rime" style on the web.xml but it doesn't help.

when I defined "none" style 
param-name :org.icefaces.ace.theme
param-value:none
the clicking on the ice:commandButton save the page style, but I am failing to change the table style to "styleClass="oddRow, evenRow" (that was the style I used on ice:dataTable in my previos IceFaces 1.8 project with"xp" style. )

can someone please explain how to define this styleClass on the table,without changing the page style on each click. 
and give me an example that show how to use styleClass on the ace:component

thanks
Tami

Answer (score 0):

To include rime.css you can include below line in you head section.

```
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="./xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css" />
```

If you want to specify your own styleclass you can use like this.

```
         <ace:dataTable style="width:200px; height:200px; cellspacing: 1px; 
          cellpadding:1px;" ></ace:dataTable>
```

If you want to use styleclass attribute then you specify external css and include the name.

Comment: I used <link..> but I still can't config the table to look like the old IceFaces 1.8 version that uses xp.css styleClass="oddRow, evenRow" and highLigth the row selector, Can you please help?